# Python: Httplib2 Module Not Found

Tags: python, httplib2

I tried to import the module but i am getting the error shown below:-

```
sh-3.2# python -V
Python 2.6.4
sh-3.2# python -c "import httplib2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

How to fix this Error?

Answer (score 31):

`httplib2` is not part of the Python standard library.  It's an external package you must install yourself.

using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/):

```
pip install httplib2
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to install the httplib2 package from your package manager.

On Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install python-httplib2`

Answer (score 10):

I suppose you could start by installing [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

Answer (score 6):

[Download](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/downloads/list) it?

Make sure it's on your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you can start by installing it like :

```
$ pip install httplib2
```

you can try the same thing with `easy install` too, or if you wanted to install in locally and not over the network then go to [httplib2 github](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2) .
Clone/download it to your computer. Now go to the downloaded httplib2 folder location and run the `setup.py` like this :

```
$ setup.py install
```

**If on windows**, *make sure you have successfully installed python first and [have set the environment variables](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) path successfully*.

This is a common command to install any module using pip or by locally downloading and looking for the foldert location>setup.py file and trying the second command mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

**FOR WINDOWS:**

if python is installed & set as environment variable

`python -m pip install httplib2`