# Httplib2 module installation on window7 64

Tags: oauth-2.0, httplib2

In Python, I used the easy_install and tried to install oauth2. Then I found it needs httplib2.

Used: easy_install httplib2 in the command prompt.
and found the httplib2 0.7.6 egg in site-packages directory.

But when I do 
import httplib2
it came back with this: ImportError: No module named httplib2

The only way I can make 'import httplib2' work is first run the setup file in the httplib2 package in the shell and then 'import oauth2'.

I don't know what to do with this, because I need oauth2 to connect to Yelp API. Please help me with this, thank you sooooooooooooo much!!!

Comment: Similar question asked try going to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882465/python-httplib2-module-not-found