# To install httplib2 in centos 5.7

Tags: python-2.7

I could not able to install httplib2 in python2.7
I already tried for steps such as:

```
yum install and
import httplib2
```

But it shows an error:

> NO MODULES FOUND

Comment: `pip install httplib2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882465/python-httplib2-module-not-found