# How to install httplib2 library - getting an error running install

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, httplib2

I am trying ton install httplib2 using python. I have both versions of python2.7.10 and python3.7.3

I have tried : `pip install httplib2`

It returns an error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'

 ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/httplib2
    copying python2/httplib2/iri2uri.py -> build/lib/httplib2
    copying python2/httplib2/certs.py -> build/lib/httplib2
    copying python2/httplib2/__init__.py -> build/lib/httplib2
    copying python2/httplib2/socks.py -> build/lib/httplib2
    copying python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt -> build/lib/httplib2
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2': Permission denied
```

How do I correctly install httplib2 using python? Why does it say "permission denied"?

Comment: You can try command You can try command 
   
     sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
or clone repository and try setup.py install. Thats alternatives can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882465/python-httplib2-module-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sudo`, like:

```
sudo pip install httplib2
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to install this by using "pip3 install httplib2"

Thanks!